# Read an xml element using Dom parser - Namespace issue

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I'm invoking a webservice and receiving response as

```
<ns2:sendGetResponse xmlns:ns2='http://test.com/bt/' xmlns:SOAP-   
ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' 
xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    instance'><return> 
  [{"Id":30477,"EmailAddress":"truech@abc.com","FirstName":"abc","LastName":"xyz","MiddleNam    e":"H","MaidenName":null,"OtherNames":null,"RaceCode":"A           }]   
</return></ns2:sendGetResponse>
```

I need to read the value inside the tag return as string. I tried Dom with and without xpath. Both of them returning null.. I think its due to the namespace issue.. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you mixing json and xml?

Comment: I've a reason for it..I've already implemented the JSON parsing...just need to know how to extract the value from <return> as a string...

Comment: `string.split("</?return>")[1]`

Comment: Will that extract all data between <return> </return> ?? can you post the code please?

Comment: What is the xpath you tried?

Comment: I tried with the XPATH - http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/return..but am sure its not the correct path....can you suggest the exact xpath to be used here? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a simple xml, I would not bother with DOM. String parsing will suffice. You could do that in different ways, but this might be the shortest.

```
String string =
"<ns2:sendGetResponse xmlns:ns2='http://test.com/bt/' xmlns:SOAP-   \r\n" +
"ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' \r\n" +
"xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-    instance'><return> \r\n" +
"  [{\"Id\":30477,\"EmailAddress\":\"truech@abc.com\",\"FirstName\":\"abc\",\"LastName\":\"xyz\",\"MiddleNam    e\":\"H\",\"MaidenName\":null,\"OtherNames\":null,\"RaceCode\":\"A           }]   \r\n" +
"</return></ns2:sendGetResponse>";

System.out.println( string.split("</?return>")[1] );
```

Comment: Thanks..I did it with Commons string utilities..but I still want to know the exact XPath for this xml with namespace..